# How to change this code for src

Tags: wordpress, src

My logo doesn't show in staging because there's no `http://`. I'm trying inspec to add `http://` so my logo can show.

That's why I must change code but I got confused on where I must edit code in folder WordPress even the code is customized from theme. How to edit src image in WordPress?

```
if ('disable' != $corporate_plus_customizer_all_values['corporate-plus-header-id-display-opt']):
    if ('logo-only' == $corporate_plus_header_alt['corporate-plus-header-logo']):
        //corporate-plus-header-id-display-opt
        if ('') :
            //function_exists('the_custom_logo')
            //the_custom_logo();
        else :
            if (!empty($corporate_plus_customizer_all_values['corporate-plus-header-logo'])):
                $corporate_plus_header_alt = get_bloginfo('name');
                ?>
                <a class="navbar-brand animated" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display')); ?>" rel="home">
                    <img src="" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($corporate_plus_header_alt); ?>"
                </a>
```

I edited like this but nothing happend. Anyone can help?

Comment: The img src in your code example is empty... I'm trying to workout what exactly you're trying to do with your code example...

Comment: sorry i'm forget. this <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $corporate_plus_customizer_all_values['corporate-plus-header-logo'] ); ?>">that code from theme, i try to change but there nothing happend.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change that kind of code in your theme. It should handle displaying logos. Could you add that code to your question? Does the alt attribute appear correctly? Are you using the [Corporate Plus](https://wordpress.org/themes/corporate-plus/) theme? What is the URL of your logo?